# Notation question: Superscript on brackets around a set with a metric

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, notation

Simplifying a bit, I encountered this notation: Where $\cal M$ and $\cal N$ are sets, each with a metric,

$[{\cal M}]^{4\epsilon} \supset [{\cal N}]^{3\epsilon}$ .

Any guesses as to the meaning of the brackets and superscript?

I'm reading $\supset$ as superset; I see no reason in the context to treat it as implication.  This $\epsilon$ is used, at an earlier stage of the same theorem, to define a small distance between elements of the sets, and to define the diameter of open balls in a covering of closely related sets.

(Further background: The notation appears on p. 1885 of ["A frequentist understanding of sets of measures"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037837580800356X) by Fierens, Rêgo, and Fine (pdf available [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/242998026_A_frequentist_understanding_of_sets_of_measures)).  The full expression there is: $P([\mbox{ch}({\cal M})]^{4\epsilon} \supset [\hat{\cal M}_{\Psi_U}]^{3\epsilon} \supset {\cal M}_f)\geq 1-\delta$, where "ch" means convex hull and $P$ is a probability.  The contents of the $\cal M$-sets are also probability measures, as it happens.  Not sure if it's worth saying more about how those three sets are defined.)

Comment: On page 1885, $[A]^\epsilon$ is defined as the $\epsilon$-enlargement of $A$ (for the distance $d$ on probability measures). Obviously $\subset$ is the inclusion. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did, I'm embarrassed.  I do understand the definition of $[A]^{\epsilon}$.  I'm working through this paper so slowly, that I had lost track of that definition--I'd forgotten it was there--by the time I read the line quoted in my question.  The fact that the definition is on the same page is especially embarrassing.   *Thank you* for taking the time to find the definition of  $[A]^{\epsilon}$.  For the last few days I've been puzzled about the line quoted in my question--I looked at the proofs, at other articles, etc., but missed the definition above it.  If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem. You could post this as an answer and even accept it after a while.

Comment: I don't feel I deserve credit for the answer.  Maybe the question shouldn't have been asked.  I could delete it.  But I asked, and that led to the answer, through your effort, @Did.  I've gotten most of what I need from the paper already, and I probably would have put the paper aside without understand the superscript notation.  (The authors' gloss of the theorem in English provided some of what I wanted to understand about it, but of course I want to understand the more precise mathematical statement of the theorem.)

Comment: Ticking the "community wiki" square ensures the author of an answer does not receive the reputation earned by upvotes on this answer (if this is your scruple).